# Defined sequence of SQL files need to migrate one after another using flyway tool

Tags: flyway

I have a scenario in which a number of SQL files need to be executed in a given order. The file names are like accounts.sql, contacts.sql, etc. Is there a way we can specify the order (probably in a text file or configuration) so that we can control the sequence? The order is important as the SQL files contain various types of instructions such as creating or altering tables, setting index, creating stored procedures and triggers etc.

Any suggestions on this would be immensely helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Flyway Teams (the paid edition) provides the `cherryPick` option. With `cherryPick` migrations are executed in the order specified. [See the `cherryPick` docs page](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/cherryPick#description).

For example, you could run:

`flyway migrate -cherryPick=1,3,2,4`

To execute migrations in the order V1, V3, V2, and finally V4.

All configuration options can be specified in a [Flyway configuration file](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/configfile). Since you can have multiple configuration files, you could create a configuration file dedicated to your `cherryPick` ordering. [See this docs page](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/configFiles).

Also note you'll have to make sure your script files confirm to [Flyway's naming conventions](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations).

Comment: Hi Mikiel, Thank you for your valuable answer. Cant we get solution through the community edition?

Comment: No, it's paid only. However note that Flyway already provides a fair amount of control through ordered versioned migrations. You may find that sequential ordering is good enough to begin with. https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#versioned-migrations